# "Waiting for deposit to be observed by beacon node pubKey=0x8b189a7f4669 status=UNKNOWN_STATUS" in Prysm Private Net

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, proof-of-stake, validators, prysm

I followed "https://www.reddit.com/r/ethstaker/comments/jrkbe2/my_checklist_to_create_and_verify_accounts_and/" to run the validator in my private devnet using staking-deposit-cli and ethdo. I changed the fork-id to 0x20000092 as I'm using capella fork. And I'm using raw-deposit-data to deposit 32ETH to the deposit contract from metamask. Still having "Waiting for deposit to be observed by beacon node pubKey=0x8b189a7f4669 status=UNKNOWN_STATUS" after running the command "./validator --datadir validatordata --accept-terms-of-use --wallet-dir /tmp/prysm --wallet-password-file /tmp/prysm/walletpwd --chain-config-file config.yml ". Is there anything else that should be done for adding the validator in private net.